# How can I solve this error InnoDB: is in the future?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

```
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 412018685584.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-06-22 00:53:17 7fe0b414a780  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140603070654336 in file fsp0fsp.cc line 3377
InnoDB: Failing assertion: xdes_mtr_get_bit(descr, XDES_FREE_BIT, header_page % FSP_EXTENT_SIZE, mtr) == FALSE
```

What is the best way to solve this? Clearly I have ibdata1 and my tables, so the data is there? Why can't it just fix this and load past it? Innodb_recovery doesn't work.

Also don't tell me to use backups, this is a 200gb+ table and that would take way too long! This was caused by a mariadb upgrade from maraidb 5.5 to mariadb 10.0.

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB doesn't provide means to fix corrupt tablespace. `innodb_force_recovery` allows you to disable some checks so you can start MySQL and dump your data. Still you have to re-create the table space and load it back.

If innondb_force_recovery doesn't work then the only way I'm aware of is to fetch records directly from InnoDB files... and re-create InnoDB tablespace from scratch.

Comment: I have the tablespace, which is the ibdata1 file. I just can't get it to load, as per the error.

Comment: I didn't claim there is no ibdata1, there is. InnoDB can't start because it's corrupt.

Comment: So what is the best way to recreate the innodb tablespace.

Comment: You move your current datadir to safe place, then run mysql_install_db, chown it, then start MySQL. But the real question is how to get data back you can upload it to the fresh instance later on